# 404 page not displaying styles

Tags: html, http-status-code-404

My 404 page is not displaying the way it is meant to be.I have placed my 404 page in the same directory of main index page (http://stthomaschss.com) as 404.html and had written in .htaccess file as

```
# DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE AND THE LINES BELOW ERRORPAGEID:QeGuBu
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

The 404 page is functioning ok if the not found error is in the same directory(http://stthomaschss.com/noexist) but if the error occurs in an other direcrtory such as http://stthomaschss.com/results/noexist the 404 page is not displaying styles linked to it...

Need help.

Comment: Try referring to the absolute path of the css file in the 404 file.

Comment: Question not directly related to your problem: Why are you using images only? This in not very contemporary. Also it's much better for SEO to write text, where text should be. E.g. "404 Oops! Page not found - Home" should be text.

Comment: Referring the absolute paths to styles worked out perfect...Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Styles are displaying correctly because the browser is looking for the `css` files in a path relative to the 404 page. Your rendered html contains:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/reset.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/grid_12.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/style.css">
```

You'll need to change this so that they reference the actual css locations, viz:

```
http://stthomaschss.com/css/reset.css
```

So you should change the css link to an absolute one, i.e.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/css/reset.css">
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea.I think I will better add <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://stthomaschss.com/css/reset.css">.So the page will be ok with any nested directories...Thanks a lot

Comment: Generally you don't want to include the domain name, as you will likely have multiple deployment environments (e.g. a development and production environment). Even just prefixing the root '/' can cause issues between virtual paths (e.g. `localhost/stthmaschss/...`) and root domain paths `www.stthmaschss.net/...`) - languages which dynamically render html often have ways of specifying 'from the root of the app' without hard coding the host or virtual root anywhere (e.g. asp.net uses `~` for this).